# Assembly Language Current location pointer

Tags: assembly, masm

Please explain this piece of code. nameSize is returning 15. How?

```
.data
aName BYTE "Abraham Lincoln",0
nameSize = ($ - aName) - 1
```

Comment: The location counter of `aname` (offset) is subtracted from the current location counter (`$`) which is 16 for you string. 1 is subtracted from it so you get 15 for `nameSize`

Comment: Related Q&A for NASM, where `$` works similarly (but not necessarily identically?)  [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47494744)

Answer (score 1):

aName represents the address of the start of the string, and $ represents the current address at the point where nameSize is defined. Since there are 16 bytes in the string, the difference between them is 16.

Comment: He did ask why it is 15 ;-) (subtracted 1 from the number)

Comment: I figured he could figure out the -1 on his own. If not, I have no help for him.

Comment: Chuckle, I figured. I had a smiley face in the comment.